# creating files based sinatra blog sinatra

Tags: sinatra, blogs

I want to create a file based blog. I have several scripts that I cannot store in a database/do not know enough about databases to store/would be a bad fit. I though it would be a good idea to create a file based blog. It not a blog per say.

The folder structure I would like to use is as follows:

```
App folder
 -- Posts 
 --- file1.erb
 --- file2.erb

 -- Posts2
 --- file3.erb
 --- file4.erb
```

How I can read the contents of the Posts folder and create an array containing the title? I know I can store them in view, but I though the views were for the site layouts.

This is what I've been doing:

```
get '/posts1/:id'  do 
    erb "posts_#{params[:id]}".to_sym
end

get '/posts2/:id'  do 
    erb "posts2_#{params[:id]}".to_sym
end
```

Note on the blog, it's not a blog, its just the easiest way to explain what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have created several apps with Sinatra that use Markdown. Please do not use ERB for content.

Markdown file could like this:

```
title: Breathe
date: 2013-08-05

Breathe.
```

Given your directory "Posts" with markdown files, you can do this:

```
Dir.glob "./app/posts/*.md" do |file|
  meta, content = File.read( file). split("\n\n", 2)
  article = OpenStruct.new YAML.load( meta)
  article.date = Time.parse article.date.to_s
  article.content = content
  article.slug = File.basename(file, '.md').gsub("_", '-')
  on "#{article.slug}" do
    erb :post, locals: { article: article }
  end
end
```

That creates routes based on the file name of your markdown file. So if it is called "Breathe" then the route is "breathe"

On your ERB file, you need to use

> to_html(article.content)

Add the helper:

```
require 'maruku'

def to_html(str)
  Maruku.new(str).to_html
end
```